# How to identify which ListView was rightclicked ?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a `ContextMenu` assigned to two `ListView`s. How to know which `ListView` it was used with so I can apply correct method? I guess `sender` is important here but how do I use it? How to know what `sender` is at this very moment?

```
private void contextMenuDokumentyDodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var dokumenty = new DocumentsGui(varKlienciID, varPortfelID);
    dokumenty.Show();
    dokumenty.FormClosed += varDocumentsGui_FormClosed;
}
```

Comment: What event is this? MSDN does not list a click event for ContextMenu

Comment: What kind of object contains your `ToolStripMenuItem`s? A `ContextMenuStrip`?

Comment: `ContextMenuStrip` which is attached to 2 listview's

Comment: ...that's not the same as ContextMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContextMenu.SourceControl
```

is your ticket.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.sourcecontrol.aspx

**EDIT**

ContextMenuStrip, you say?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx

Comment: It's nice but how do I get `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem` tell me which ContextMenu used it ?

Comment: ... I thought you said there was only one ContextMenu for two ListViews?

Comment: yes I created ContextMenuStrip and assigned it to two listviews

Comment: So why do you need to determine at run time who the ContextMenuStrip is? You only have one.

Comment: I have 2 `ListView`'s and one `ContextMenuStrip` which is assinged to both ListView's. I need to know which ListView was right clicked from ToolStripMenuItem that was used .. to distinguish whether it's Client Related or Customer Related (similar ListView's). This seems a bit easier then having 2 exactly same ContextMenuStrip's that are exactly the same and only difference is how they call one method.

Comment: ... I agree. What isn't clear about this?

     MyContextMenu.SourceControl

The result will be an Object containing one of the ListViews

Comment: How to get ContextMenuStrip from (sender) ? This is a problem. Using it like this       
            `ListView lv = (ListView) contextMenuDokumenty.SourceControl;` doesn't bring any useful result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4935/discussion-between-sq33g-and-madboy)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
ListView listViewClicked = (ListView) sender;
```

---

**EDIT** (after comments)

The `sender` is the `ToolStripMenuItem`, so use a cast to get it, then use `GetCurrentParent` method to get the `ContextMenuStrip` containing the item, then use the `SourceControl` property to get the control displaying your menu, as suggested by **@sq33G**:

```
ListView lv = ((ToolStripMenuItem) sender).GetCurrentParent().SourceControl;
```

Maybe you'll need also to cast the `GetCurrentParent` return value to a `ContextMenuStrip`.

Comment: I didn't. I will try it just was looking for a way to tell what's hiding under `sender` for any particular usage? How to tell as it's widely used all over so would prefer additional / general explanation.

Comment: @MadBoy: Well to answer your question, `sender` is different depending on the click event. If the cast works, you'll know that in this case, `sender` is the clicked `ListView`.

Comment: `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'.` So it is actually different cast :-)

Comment: There's no .SourceControl on .GetCurrentParent :-) After you add .GetCurrentParent() all you get is `ToolStrip`

Comment: @MadBoy: Did you try `ListView lv = (ContextMenuStrip) (((ToolStripMenuItem) sender).GetCurrentParent()).SourceControl;`?